# Is "publish quality paper" grammatical?

Tags: grammaticality

Is "publish quality paper" in the following sentence grammatical?

> I do not have problems in publishing paper, the only problem is to
>   publish quality and impactful paper.

Answer (score 1):

You asked the wrong question. The sentence is not grammatically correct, but not because of the phrase you highlighted.

A proper way to say it will be:
I do not have any problems in publishing papers; the only problem I have is to publish quality and impactful papers.

An improved way of structuring this will be:
I have no problem in producing a large amount of publications. The issue I have is creating quality and impactful papers.